# Excel missing columns

Tags: python, excel, pandas, excel-formula

I have 2 excel spreadsheets. both Spreadsheets have similar columns(more than 50 columns) but 1 spreadsheet has more columns. for example, A_1.xlsx has 50 columns and B_1.xlsx has 90 columns(50 columns are exact of a_1 and 40 are different) how do I take out(filter or fetch those different columns alone how should I approach this problem.

Comment: Are there column names in the top row?

Comment: Yes you can say A1, B1 and so on

Comment: To clarify, suppose A_1.xlsx has two columns containing numbers and B_1.xlsx has three columns containing numbers, meaning B_1.xlsx has an extra column. How would you know which of the columns in B_1.xlsx is the extra one? Would A_1.xlsx have just a single worksheet containing column names in cells A1 and B1, and would B_1.xlsx have a single worksheet containing column names in cells A1, B1 and C1?

Comment: Do the columns have names such as "Age" "Size" or similar? Are columns that match, the same in the two sets of data? If so, copy sets of columns both to a new Sheet, from A, then a blank column, then from B. Insert a row at the top where you enter A for those from A and B above those from B. Then select all, and Data | Sort | Options | Sort left to right.  Insert another row at the top, and in A1 put if(A2=B2,"Can delete","Keep")

Comment: Or if data is not too huge, copy from source and in the sheet where you will compare/filter, do Paste Special | Transpose. Add a column where you enter As and then Bs, and use a Pivot Table. i.e. it's easier to do some processes on rows rather than columns.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you a dataframe that does contains only the additional columns from df1

```
df1[set(df1.columns) - set(df.columns)]
```